# Fitting a line to the mean values of a multilevel variable using geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga42rg8ch3hd9fy/datos.csv?dl=0).

I create a plot representing on the y-axis "value" and on the x-axis each of the levels of "Column_S", which contains levels from S1 to S10. All this grouped by "VS" and "Inst" (with a facet_grid) and "Estatus" with colour.

```
na.omit(data) %>% 
  group_by(VS,Estatus,Inst, Columna_S) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(value), 
            desvio = sd(value),                             
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),            
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) -> stats

ggplot() +  
  geom_errorbar(
    data = stats,   
    aes(x = Columna_S,
        ymin = intervalo_inf,
        ymax = intervalo_sup,
        color = Estatus   
    ), width = 0.4 )+
  geom_point(data = stats,
             aes(x = Columna_S,
                 y = media,
             color = Estatus))+
  facet_grid(Inst ~ VS, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic()
```

However, instead of an independent point for each mean, I'd like to use `geom_smooth` to plot a line (plus standard error) that fits the means along the x-axis.

I have tried the code below, but it is not generating the desired outcome.

```
na.omit(data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Columna_S,y=value,colour=Estatus, na.rm = TRUE) ) +
  geom_smooth(aes(fill=Estatus,na.rm = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=25), limits=c(0,100))+
  facet_grid(Institution~Value_system, scales = "free")+
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have factors on the x-axis, I am not so sure it makes sense to put a smooth line through it, but if thats what you need, it goes like this:

```
data %>% 
filter(!is.na(Columna_S)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Columna_S,y=value,colour=Estatus)) +
geom_smooth(aes(group=Estatus)) +
facet_grid(Inst~VS, scales = "free")+
theme_classic()
```

[image]

You can consider putting a line through all the means:

```
data %>% 
filter(!is.na(Columna_S)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Columna_S,y=value,colour=Estatus)) +
stat_summary(aes(group=Estatus),fun=mean,geom="line") +
facet_grid(Inst~VS, scales = "free")+
theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @StupidWolf, athough when I try to set the same scale in the y axis `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=25), limits=c(0,100))` it doesn't draw the se properly. I think this has to do with the fact I have factors on the x axis. Thanks for the answer anyway, it was helpful.

Comment: yeah i noticed that when making the plot.. the issue is that when smoothing, the error bar goes beyond your limits. so you can either change the smoothing parameter or omit the standard error with se=FALSE

Answer (score 1):

It is a year late, but…

I have a similar problem, I have an ordered factor and want to fit a straight line through the levels, but the solution above does not work: no errors given, just no lines on the plot.

The solution I have found works because in ggplot you can plot datasets on top of each other (you are not restricted to one data frame).
So,

1. create a numeric version of the factor
2. Plot the box plots using the faceting etc as above
3. then plot that on top of the factor layer a geom_smooth layer
   mentioning the data= (same data frame) and
4. use the numeric factor as x for this layer, keep the same y.

It works! Because the factor values = the numeric values the lines plot in the right place.
If it is still needed I can add the code.

Comment: Hi @DaveG, I came across your answer today. Thanks! I solved the issue too, but I think it is a great idea to publish your code so that other users can use it in the future!